# Install spyder independently(without Anaconda, python x,y) on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, spyder

I was trying to install spyder on windows 10 with the python version 3.6+. But it was not working. It was giving me the following error. Seriously, i don't know what these error means. Error:

An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "c:\python36\lib\site packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 269, in 
main()
File "c:\python36\lib\site packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 237, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "c:\python36\lib\site packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "c:\python36\lib\site packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in 
from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
File "c:\python36\lib\site packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 41, in 
""")
ImportError: 
IPython 6.0+ does not support Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, or 3.2.
When using Python 2.7, please install IPython 5.x LTS Long Term Support version.
Beginning with IPython 6.0, Python 3.3 and above is required.

See IPython `README.rst` file for more information:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/README.rst
```

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted all the previous version of the python from the C drive manually.
then, install the python 3.6.5(latest stable version available) at the time of posting.

Sometimes i faced issues in installing python and access it through windows cmd.
To resolve this, during the installation of python 3.6.5, opt for customized installation and when it ask for the folder in which to install it.
just create a folder in C drive with name Python36 and install python in this folder. Means install python in `C:\Python36`

and add two paths to the Path variable using the following commands.

`setx path "%path%;C:\Python36;"`
`setx path "%path%;C:\Python36\Scripts;"`

and then, try python.

To check, just type `python --version` 
if it is working, python is ready to use

Then, i tried to install SIP package from pip. but pip was not working.
then, i manually install and upgrade the pip on my system using the following commands windows command line,

```
python -m pip install pip==9.0.0  # will install pip
pip install -U pip                # will upgrade pip
```

pip got installed successfully and the version i checked was 
pip 9.0.3 using the following command on windows command line:
`pip --version`

After that just run the following commands from cmd:

```
pip3 install SIP

pip3 install PyQt5

pip install spyder
```

Then, to check either spyder is working or not, just go the directory in which python is installed. e.g. on my sysytem, directory is `C:\Python36\Scripts`. search for `spyder3`app and click on it. and create a shortcut for it.

Versions:
`PyQt5 (5.9.2)`
`sip (4.19.8)`

Comment: It endup messing up existing jupyter

Comment: try just `pip install spyder`

Answer (score 0):

Install the `spyder` using pip:

```
pip install spyder
```